# clang-format breaks lint annotations

Tags: c++, lint, clang-format

We use lint in our codebase at work for C/C++, I'm trying to start integrating clang-format in my workflow as well.

Unfortunately, lint occasionally requires annotations to ignore a specific check, either of the format:

```
/*lint -[annotation] */
```

or

```
//lint -[annotation]
```

Specifically, if there's a space between the opening token for the comment and 'lint', it doesn't recognize it as an annotation directive. Unfortunately, the default settings I have for clang-format see that as an error and helpfully insert the space.

Is there any way to get clang-format to recognize comments matching that pattern and leave them alone? Right now I'm using 3.4, but could upgrade if needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Clang-format has a `CommentPragmas' option that is

> A regular expression that describes comments with special meaning, which should not be split into lines or otherwise changed.

When I put the following line in my .clang-format file, my Lint comments remain untouched.

```
CommentPragmas:  '^lint'
```

Other comments that still have "lint" in them, but are not Lint comments still get formatted.

Answer (score 17):

You can disable clang-format for that section of your file by using:

```
int formatted_code;
// clang-format off
    void    unformatted_code  ;
// clang-format on
void formatted_code_again;
```

See the [Disabling formating on a piece of code](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#disabling-formatting-on-a-piece-of-code) section.

Comment: Any idea when this feature became available? I've been unable to successfully build on mac so using a prebuilt version _clang-format version 3.5 (tags/checker/checker-276)_ and these do not seem to have any affect.

Comment: Wed Aug  6 08:40:26 2014: [r214966 - clang-format: Add special comments to disable formatting.](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20140804/111937.html), 03 Sep 2014: [Release of Clang 3.5.0](http://llvm.org/releases/)