# How to prevent clang-format to add space after comment char?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have some comments in my code:

```
//asdf
```

when I use clang-format on it, it adds a space just after the // characters:

```
// asdf
```

How can I prevent that from happening in the clang-format configuration ?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting... neither the [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) nor `clang-format -dump-config | grep -i 'space\|comment'` seem to mention anything about that.

Comment: `SpacesBeforeTrailingComments` appears to mean spaces _before_ the `//` if it trails on a code line, but the documentation isn't terribly clear; worth giving it a try, at least.

Comment: Earlier, I've had a look at the [clang::format::FormatStyle class documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/structclang_1_1format_1_1FormatStyle.html) (which _"is used to configure the formatting to follow specific guidelines"_)... still couldn't find a suitable option for controlling this behavior. As jpw said, your best bet would be to implement the feature in a custom-built clang-format. Or... perhaps you could submit a report in [the LLVM Bug Tracking System](http://llvm.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combining the answers to these two questions should solve the problem:

- [clang-format breaks lint annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880990/clang-format-breaks-lint-annotations)
- [What regex will match every character except comma ',' or semi-colon ';'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409162/what-regex-will-match-every-character-except-comma-or-semi-colon)

So the following line in your `.clang-format` file should do the trick (I did not test it):

```
CommentPragmas:  '^[^ ]'
```

That tells clang-format not to mess with comments that start with something other than a space.

[For completeness, clang-format documentation here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

Comment: I tested this (using clang-format 3.7) and it does indeed seem to work.

Comment: With clang-format 3.5 it also works like a charm :) Thanks